# Highcharts does not load my data properly

Tags: highcharts

I've tried several types of outputs. What I already have is:

JSON Output:

```
["[Date.UTC(2015,6,13,16,41,05), 3]","[Date.UTC(2015,7,15,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2015,8,18,16,41,05), 4]","[Date.UTC(2015,9,28,16,41,05), 3]","[Date.UTC(2015,10,20,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2015,10,28,16,41,05), 5]","[Date.UTC(2015,11,13,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2015,11,21,16,41,05), 2]","[Date.UTC(2015,11,24,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2015,11,25,16,41,05), 2]","[Date.UTC(2015,11,28,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,03,16,41,05), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,09,16,41,05), 4]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,14,16,41,05), 6]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,17,16,41,05), 3]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,18,16,41,05), 3]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,20,16,41,05), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,21,16,41,05), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,22,16,41,05), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,23,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,24,16,41,05), 5]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,25,13,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,25,16,41,00), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,25,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,27,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,28,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,0,29,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,09,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,10,16,41,05), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,11,16,41,05), 3]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,15,16,41,05), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,18,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,21,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,23,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,24,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,25,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,26,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,1,28,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,2,01,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,2,02,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,2,05,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,2,12,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,2,21,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,3,25,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,4,05,16,41,05), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,4,11,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,4,12,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,4,24,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,4,25,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,5,01,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,5,12,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,5,25,10,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,5,25,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,6,01,10,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,6,01,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,6,02,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,6,25,16,21,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,6,25,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,7,13,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,7,28,16,41,05), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,8,20,16,41,05), 3]","[Date.UTC(2016,8,29,16,41,05), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,9,01,14,20,18), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,9,09,14,20,18), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,9,10,14,20,18), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,9,28,14,20,18), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,9,30,14,20,18), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,10,01,13,44,29), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,10,06,08,26,18), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,10,10,13,44,29), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,10,13,13,44,29), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,10,14,19,13,42), 4]","[Date.UTC(2016,10,15,23,27,39), 3]","[Date.UTC(2016,11,06,19,04,06), 3]","[Date.UTC(2016,11,08,10,49,28), 3]","[Date.UTC(2016,11,10,23,01,44), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,11,14,21,27,44), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,23,27,44), 2]","[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,23,27,53), 3]","[Date.UTC(2016,11,18,18,06,28), 1]","[Date.UTC(2016,11,21,20,06,28), 3]","[Date.UTC(2016,11,23,20,06,20), 5]","[Date.UTC(2016,11,29,20,18,18), 3]","[Date.UTC(2017,0,03,20,06,32), 3]"]
```

That looks OK!
The works I've done on PHP is:

```
header("Content-type: text/json");

    if($callback == 'cart-filling') {
        // Count cart rows
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query
            ->select('*')
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__product_shoppingcart'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('date') . $scope);
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();
        $ret = array();
        foreach($results as $result) {
            //$x = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $date = new DateTime($result->date);
            $month = date_format($date, 'm');
            $monthInt = (int) $month-1;
            $date_part1 = date_format($date, 'Y');
            $date_part2 = $monthInt;
            $date_part3 = date_format($date, 'd');
            $date_part4 = date_format($date, 'H');
            $date_part5 = date_format($date, 'i');
            $date_part6 = date_format($date, 's');
            $formatted_date = (int) $date_part1 . ',' . (int) $date_part2 . ',' . (int) $date_part3 . ',' . (int) $date_part4 . ',' . (int) $date_part5 . ',' . (int) $date_part6;
            /*
            $date = new DateTime($result->date);
            $x = date_format($date, "Y-m-d H:i:s");
            */
            $x = $formatted_date;
            $y = $result->qty;
            //array_push($ret, array($x, $y));

            //extract $row;
           //$x = 'Date.UTC(' . $x . ')'; // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
           $data[] = "[Date.UTC($x), $y]";
        }
    }
    // Returning JSON string regarding the given callback and dtae
    echo json_encode($data);
```

My AJAX call says:

```
function cartFilling() {
        var url = 'components/com_product/views/reports/callback.php?callback=cart-filling&date='+date_scope;
        jQuery.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            Highcharts.chart('cartFilling', {
                chart: {
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Shopping Cart Filling Actions'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                            'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Carts Filled'
                    },
                    type: 'number'
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        fillColor: {
                            linearGradient: {
                                x1: 0,
                                y1: 0,
                                x2: 0,
                                y2: 1
                            },
                            stops: [
                                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                            ]
                        },
                        marker: {
                            radius: 2
                        },
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        },
                        threshold: null
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    type: 'area',
                    name: 'Cart Filling',
                    data: data
                }]
            });
        });
    }
```

So, "data" already is:

```
[Date.UTC(2015,6,13,16,41,5), 3],[Date.UTC(2015,7,15,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2015,8,18,16,41,5), 4],[Date.UTC(2015,9,28,16,41,5), 3],[Date.UTC(2015,10,20,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2015,10,28,16,41,5), 5],[Date.UTC(2015,11,13,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2015,11,21,16,41,5), 2],[Date.UTC(2015,11,24,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2015,11,25,16,41,5), 2],[Date.UTC(2015,11,28,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,0,3,16,41,5), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,0,9,16,41,5), 4],[Date.UTC(2016,0,14,16,41,5), 6],[Date.UTC(2016,0,17,16,41,5), 3],[Date.UTC(2016,0,18,16,41,5), 3],[Date.UTC(2016,0,20,16,41,5), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,0,21,16,41,5), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,0,22,16,41,5), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,0,23,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,0,24,16,41,5), 5],[Date.UTC(2016,0,25,13,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,0,25,16,41,0), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,0,25,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,0,27,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,0,28,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,0,29,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,1,9,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,1,10,16,41,5), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,1,11,16,41,5), 3],[Date.UTC(2016,1,15,16,41,5), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,1,18,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,1,21,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,1,23,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,1,24,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,1,25,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,1,26,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,1,28,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,2,1,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,2,2,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,2,5,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,2,12,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,2,21,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,3,25,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,4,5,16,41,5), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,4,11,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,4,12,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,4,24,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,4,25,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,5,1,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,5,12,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,5,25,10,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,5,25,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,6,1,10,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,6,1,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,6,2,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,6,25,16,21,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,6,25,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,7,13,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,7,28,16,41,5), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,8,20,16,41,5), 3],[Date.UTC(2016,8,29,16,41,5), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,9,1,14,20,18), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,9,9,14,20,18), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,9,10,14,20,18), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,9,28,14,20,18), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,9,30,14,20,18), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,10,1,13,44,29), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,10,6,8,26,18), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,10,10,13,44,29), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,10,13,13,44,29), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,10,14,19,13,42), 4],[Date.UTC(2016,10,15,23,27,39), 3],[Date.UTC(2016,11,6,19,4,6), 3],[Date.UTC(2016,11,8,10,49,28), 3],[Date.UTC(2016,11,10,23,1,44), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,11,14,21,27,44), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,23,27,44), 2],[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,23,27,53), 3],[Date.UTC(2016,11,18,18,6,28), 1],[Date.UTC(2016,11,21,20,6,28), 3],[Date.UTC(2016,11,23,20,6,20), 5],[Date.UTC(2016,11,29,20,18,18), 3],[Date.UTC(2017,0,3,20,6,32), 3]
```

In addition,
I've tried serialize these ways as well:

```
data: [data]
```

and

```
data: ([data])
```

The most funny part is, when I insert the generated data manually for "data:" it works. But when I call its var it does nothing. Wasted 4 days of mine!
What's wring with me? What's going on here? I'm tired of waiting, asking wrong questions, getting wrong answers and receiving negative points for my questions :( Please somebody expert in Highcharts respond otherwise I do something so bad with this Laptop!

Thank you

Comment: You data and how you load it to the chart dont seem to be correct. "Date.UTC" part can be delivered only as string and evaluate later by js. Try to use data.map(row => eval(row)) like in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hk2c5awg/)

Comment: I couldn't sleep since tonight! You just took me out of the hell Morgan! Thank you thousands times.